# How to get Laravel model of authorized user?

Tags: laravel, authentication, model

How can I get the user model in Laravel like this?

```
$userModel::find( auth()->id() );
```

I mean, auth user instance is already loaded, but in what above do we do the request to db...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

```
auth()->user();
```

or using the `Auth` facade:

```
Auth::user();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get loggedIn user info like below

```
$user = auth()->user() ? auth()->user() : null;
```